# fetch() и подгрузка постов из JSON

Tags: javascript, fetch

Я хочу динамически подгружать по 10 постов пролистывая ленту. Я понимаю, что нужно это повесить на scroll. Но боже я ума не приложу, как это сделать? Буду благодарен даже если подскажите, где почитать по этому поводу, а то я вообще ни бум бум.

```
window.onload = () => {
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/152f9j")
            .then((response) => {
                response.json().then((data) => {
                    const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];               
                let imgCont = document.getElementById("img-container");
            for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                let dateTMP = new Date(`${data.data[i].createdAt}`);
                let postWrp = document.createElement("div");
                postWrp.classList.add("post-wrp");

                postWrp.innerHTML = `<div id="img-container">
    <div class="title-wrp">${data.data[i].title}</div>
    <div class="post-and-image">
      <img src="${data.data[i].image}">
      <div class="description-wrp">${data.data[i].description}
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="footer-row">
        <div class="time-wrp">${dateTMP.getDate()} ${monthNames[dateTMP.getMonth()]} ${dateTMP.getHours()}:${dateTMP.getMinutes()}</div>
        <div class="tags-wrp">${data.data[i].tags}</div>
    </div>` 
                document.body.appendChild(postWrp);
            }
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })}
```

Comment: Что-то не видно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> хочу динамически подгружать по 10 постов пролистывая ленту. Я понимаю,что нужно это повесить на scroll.

Для этого примера взято 5 первых элементов, остальные добавляются/подгружаются в `body` по мере прокрутки. Вы можете поменять, на число которое вам больше нравиться, только не забудьте, если элементов всего 10, прокручивать для подгрузки будет нечего.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  var ar = [] // Массив для отложенной загрузки
  fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/152f9j", {
      mode: 'cors'
    })
    .then((response) => {
      response.json().then((data) => {

        const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        let imgCont = document.getElementById("img-container");
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          let dateTMP = new Date(`${data.data[i].createdAt}`);
          let postWrp = document.createElement("div");
          postWrp.classList.add("post-wrp");

          postWrp.innerHTML = `<div id="img-container">
    <div class="title-wrp">${data.data[i].title}</div>
    <div class="post-and-image">
      <img src="${data.data[i].image}">
      <div class="description-wrp">${data.data[i].description}
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="footer-row">
        <div class="time-wrp">${dateTMP.getDate()} ${monthNames[dateTMP.getMonth()]} ${dateTMP.getHours()}:${dateTMP.getMinutes()}</div>
        <div class="tags-wrp">${data.data[i].tags}</div>
    </div>`

          if (i >= 5) { // <---- Отложенный показ, если надо поменять кол-во элементов
            ar.push(postWrp)
          } else { // Первые 5 элементов подружаются сразу
            document.body.appendChild(postWrp);
          }
        }

      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // На вешаем событие на scroll body
  document.querySelector('body').onscroll = function(e) {
    let b = document.body
    if (this.scrollY >= b.scrollHeight / 2) { // Половина и более экрана прокрученно
      if (this.scrollY % 100 && ar.length) { // Подгружает если в массиве есть элементы

        b.appendChild(ar.shift()); // Добавляет элемент
      }
    }

  };

}
```

Comment: спасибо большое,
но почему-то когда я вешаю через addEventListener то ничего не работает

Comment: @tranntus не за что. Это уже другой вопрос, задайте отдельно. К новому вопросу, добавьте код с вашими попытками, опишите, что работает, а что нет. Какого результата, хотели бы добиться.